# Package dependencies cannot be resolved.. Pleaseee help

Tags: dropbox

I'm new to ubuntu. I don't have any knowledge about it. Just installed it yesterday.

So, in the ubuntu software center I'm unable to install any app.

Also, when I'm trying to add an optional add-on to ubuntu restricted extras, I'm getting error. That add-on is necessary to run my videos. Please help me..

Feeling helpless.

Screenshot 1 - https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi86ahr2jyliof5/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-01%2001%3A09%3A22.png?dl=0

Screenshot 2 - https://www.dropbox.com/s/q609ulu3cjrvm3v/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-01%2001%3A09%3A28.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I know a couple things you can try. I'm not sure if you're new to Linux, but I'll write this so that even if you're completely new you should be comfortable with it.

Open up the Terminal with `ctrl+alt+t`.
(If the terminal is intimidating, don't worry--you'll just be copying and pasting :)

Then run these commands. (If you want to copy and paste them, you need to press `ctrl+SHIFT+v`, not `ctrl+v` like usual. This is just how Terminal works in Linux/Ubuntu.)

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -yr
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Do these commands work?